# Why is my Page not rerendering when the Context changes

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have a Base Context where some base stuff is stored like the current logged-in user.
I have a User Page which should display the Informations but it doesn't re-render when the Context changes. As first, the Context is of course empty (isLoaded = false). And when the init (Get user from API) is done, the isLoaded and base.loaded is set to true. The Context updates, but the User page doesn't update and keeps showing "Loading...". My Page also is wrapped in the Context correctly

Context:

```
"use client"

import { createContext, useContext, ReactNode, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Base from '@/scripts/classes/Base.class';

const BaseContext = createContext<Base | undefined>(undefined);

export const BaseProvider: React.FC<{ children: ReactNode }> = ({ children }) => {
  const base = new Base("123");
  const [ isLoaded, setLoaded ] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    base.init()
      .then(() => {
        console.log("Initialized base")
        setLoaded(true);
       })
       .catch(() => { console.log("ERROR ON INITIALIZATION")})
  }, []);

  if(!isLoaded) return "Loading Base...";

  return <BaseContext.Provider value={base}>{children}</BaseContext.Provider>;
};

export const useBase = () => {
  const context = useContext(BaseContext);
  if (!context) {
    throw new Error("useBase must be used within a BaseProvider");
  }
  return context;
};
```

And this is my Page:

```
"use client"

export default function UserProfile({ params }: Props) {
    const base = useBase();

    if(!base.loaded) {
        return "Loading User...";
    } else {
        return "Loaded " + base.users.me.username;
    }
}
```

Here is my Base class:

```
export default class Base {
    loaded: boolean = false;
    users: UserManager;

    locale: any;

    api: API;
    websocket: Websocket;

    constructor(token: string) {
        this.users = new UserManager(this);
        this.api = new API(this, token);
        this.websocket = new Websocket();
    }

    async init() {
        this.users.me = await this.users.fetch(1);
        this.locale = { hello: "Hello" }; //Fetch from URL later

        this.loaded = true;
    }
}
```

I'm absolutely sure that base is initialized and that the user is set correctly. It just doesn't update the page.

I want that the user is shown after the Base loaded

Comment: `const base = new Base("123");` This is the object you're sharing through the context. Since you apparently expect `base.loaded` to be false, could you please show us the code for the Base class?

Comment: Yes i just edited my post and added the class

Comment: I suspect that react doses’t detect Base class mutation by default. You would need to have Base return some result and set that result with useState

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like React doesn't directly detect class updates.

I fixed it by adding a "hash" to the base and a state which watches the hash. Every time I update something, I have to call `this.update()`, which changes the hash and triggers a `setState`.

I'm pretty sure that there's a better way but, for now, this is the best I found.

Base Provider:

```
const BaseContext = createContext<Base | undefined>(undefined);

export const BaseProvider: React.FC<{ children: ReactNode }> = ({ children }) => {
  const [ base, setBase ] = useState<Base | undefined>(undefined);
  

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const _base = new Base("123");
      await _base.init();

      setBase(_base);
    })();
  }, []);

  if(!base || !base.loaded) return "Loading Overlay"

  return (
    <BaseContext.Provider value={ base }>
      {children}
    </BaseContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useBase = () => {
  const context = useContext(BaseContext);
  
  const [ _, setBaseHash ] = useState(Math.random());
  context?.onUpdate(() => setBaseHash(context.hash));

  if (!context) {
    throw new Error("useBase must be used within a BaseProvider");
  }
  return context;
};
```

Base class:

```
export default class Base {
    hash: number = 0;
    loaded: boolean = false;
    users: UserManager;

    locale: any;

    api: API;
    websocket: Websocket;

    private updateListeners: Function[] = [];

    constructor(token: string) {
        this.users = new UserManager(this);
        this.api = new API(this, token);
        this.websocket = new Websocket();
    }

    async init() {
        await this.users.fetch(1);
        //this.locale = fetch from url...;

        this.loaded = true;

        await this.websocket.connect(config.socketUrl);
        this.websocket.authorize(this.api.token, [ "Users" ]);
            
        this.websocket.on("UserUpdate", (newUser: Partial<UserStructure>) => {
           //update this.users.cache logic

            this.update();
        })
    }

    onUpdate(fn: Function) {
        this.updateListeners.push(fn);
    }

    update() {
        this.hash = Math.random();
        this.updateListeners.forEach(fn => fn());
    }
}
```

And this is the page:

```
export default function UserProfile({ params }: Props) {
    const base = useBase();

    const userId = parseInt(params.userId) || 0;
    const user = base.users.cache.get(userId);

    if(!user) return "User not found";

   //do something with user
}
```